# NSMutableArray works in ViewDidLoad, but not in DidSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

Menu.h

```
@interface Menu : UITableViewController {    
    NSMutableArray *arrayCellCollectionOrder;
    NSMutableDictionary *dictCellCollection;
    NSMutableDictionary *dictCellIndividual;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayCellCollectionOrder;

@end
```

Menu.m

ViewDidLoad works as normal.

```
@synthesize arrayCellCollectionOrder;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // Codes to read in data from PLIST
    // This part works

    NSString *errorDesc = nil;
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSString *plistPath;
    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"InfoTableDict.plist"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"InfoTableDict" ofType:@"plist"];
    }

    NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
    NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                        propertyListFromData:plistXML
                                        mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                        format:&format
                                        errorDescription:&errorDesc];

    if (!temp) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
    }

    arrayCellCollectionOrder = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];
    arrayCellCollectionOrder = [temp objectForKey:@"CellCollectionOrder"]; 

    // I can access `arrayCellCollectionOrder` here, it's working.

}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath works as normal. I can access `arrayCellCollectionOrder`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhotoCell";
    PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PhotoCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[PhotoCell class]]) {
                cell = (PhotoCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Copy the specific dictionary from CellCollection to Cell Individual
    dictCellIndividual = [dictCellCollection objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayCellCollectionOrder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    cell.photoCellTitle.text = [dictCellIndividual objectForKey:@"Title"];     // Load cell title
    cell.photoCellImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictCellIndividual objectForKey:@"ThumbnailFilename"]]];        // Load cell image name

    return cell;

}
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath NOT WORKING. I cannot access `arrayCellCollectionOrder`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Browser
NSMutableArray *arrayPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"indexPath.row = %d", indexPath.row);        // Returns the row number i touched, works.

    NSLog(@"arrayCellCollectionOrder = %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayCellCollectionOrder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]);        // DOES NOT WORK.

    // Copy the specific dictionary from CellCollection to Cell Individual
    dictCellIndividual = [dictCellCollection objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayCellCollectionOrder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];        // This similar line gives error too.

    ...   ...
    ...   ...
    ...   ...
    ...   ...

}
```

Error is:
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (0)'

i.e.: I clicked on row `1`, but `arrayCellCollectionOrder` is NULL.
There should have data in `arrayCellCollectionOrder` as it's declared in ViewDidLoad.

Is there something that I missed out?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arrayCellCollectionOrder = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];
arrayCellCollectionOrder = [temp objectForKey:@"CellCollectionOrder"];
```

Do you see what you are doing to `arrayCellCollectionOrder`?  You first assign it to a new NSMutableArray (and retain it needlessly), and then you immediately orphan the array and assign `arrayCellCollectionOrder` to another object that you are getting from the `temp` dictionary.  In other words, that first line isn't doing anything for you, other than create a leaked mutable array.

If the second line is correct and you are getting a valid object and that is what you want, then the problem is that I don't see where that object is getting retained.  As long as it is in the dictionary, it is probably retained, but if temp is discarded, then its members are released.  If you did a

```
self.arrayCellCollectionOrder = [temp objectForKey:@"CellCollectionOrder"];
```

then the setter would retain it.

Comment: Thanks!
Found out my mistake..
Changed to the below line worked too.

    arrayCellCollectionOrder = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayCellCollectionOrder = [[temp objectForKey:@"CellCollectionOrder"] retain];

Comment: You're leaking if you do it that way.  Why are you doing an alloc and init at all?  Secondly, you have a @property defined, and setter and getters in place (@synthesize), so why are you doing a manual retain when you can use your setter?  Do what I suggested:  1)  delete 

arrayCellCollectionOrder = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];

2) change the other line to:


self.arrayCellCollectionOrder = [temp objectForKey:@"CellCollectionOrder"];

Comment: Memory management is new to me. I guess you're right.
`self.arrayCellCollectionOrder` is the proper way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Try to understand why you are making those changes, and I think it will prevent headaches in the future.  If you assign an object to a variable and assign another object to that same variable, then the first object could very well have become orphaned and possibly leaked.  Also, you don't have to use setters and getters, so you won't need to define property or synthesize, if you are doing the retains manually like you were going to do.  But what property and synthesize let you do is to allow access of your class's instance vars by other class's.  (I am oversimplifying)